# Resources filled up with a lot of dbus-daemon

Tags: process, d-bus

On an ARM board, that run a custom Yocto environment, sometimes I notice the os not responds anymore. I had hard-time to type `ps aux` and I discovered there were hundreds of such a process:

```
/usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session
```

I know the `dbus` is a mechanism to exchange data between applications, but how to find out which application floods my system?

Comment: Found it! Every time I launch any application (even a simple C++ "Hello World") from QtCreator, it creates 3 new `dbus-daemon` processes that stay there even when the application closes.

Comment: That's great but how did you solve it?

Comment: @Ramast rebooting periodically during debugging... since when it runs normally (i.e. not launching applications from QtCreator) the issue was not there.